# Need help in SQL Server Remote Access

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

how to connect two laptops to share a database using windows form application? i mean i've installed mssql server 2008 in my laptop, i need to make windows form application so my friend can modify the database from his laptop, it's not in LAN , we have to use Internet as medium to connect, it'd be helpful if anyone can show me some directions like how connection strings should be. thanks :)

Comment: Have you considered reading a tutorial about SQL Server? COnnectionstrings, the documentation of setting up sql server is all you need, except you MUST be on a common network - exposing a database server to the internet, especially if you do not know what you do, is basically telling a lot of bad people "Hey, own me".

Comment: TY, I read through articles and watched vids, it's working in LAN , i just want to make it available from anywhere, ofc i'm filtering IP address via firewall, i'm a IT student, what the connecting Method difference between LAN and Internet, what i'm missing?

Comment: That it is a bad idea in genera. Either make a LAN (VPN to log into one location) or use a web service and an application server. Exposing a SQL Server to the internet is not a good approach.

Comment: so, is thr no way i can access my home database outside LAN? i can do basic SQL injection Filterings also, and there is no Aliens Secrets either. if it possible i'd just like do it :)

Comment: If you think your computer owned by a bot network is good, go ahead, but do not ask anyone with some common sense to help you. Use a VPN. Most home routers shoudl be able to allow your friend to connect to your local network. Once in a VPN he is on the same logical network.

Comment: Thank you guys for all support and answers, i did it, i used Hamachi as my VPN and its working as it should be :)

Comment: Great. gratulations. That is a good setup.

Comment: lemme ask one crazy thing, is threre something like Hamachi API or something? so i can code them to my program as inbuilt ?

Comment: I haven o idea because my VPN's are done by either windows server or ISP grade professional routers (Mikrotik).

Comment: how secure is that hamachi? i mean it says it use AES-256bit encrypt, hope thats to the connection, its very secure to passive attacks, i thinking about log In it seem vulnerable to brute force attack, thats concerns me :/

Comment: which part of "I do not use hamachi" do you not understand? I do not care how safe it is - I use a professional setup. VPN's are built based on certificates of my own inhouse certificate authority. I assume hamachi is safe enough for home use - but that is another question you should ask (on superuser.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider looking into [this](http://www.techpint.com/programming/error-26-%E2%80%93-error-locating-serverinstance-specified-sql-server). If you search for Error 40 or Error 26 SQL Server. You will get lot of links for connecting SQL Server remotely both on LAN and WAN.

Take a look at this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) as well. Screenshots are added here

There are multiple steps involved

1. Enable default login (sa) - not a good practice
2. Enable remote connection on sql server
3. Enable SqlBrowser service - either through Sql Server configuration manager or type services.msc on Run(Ctrl + R)
4. Add SqlBrowser.exe to firewall exception
5. Open TCP port 1433 and add it to firewall
6. Enable TCP, NamedPipe in Sql Server Configuration manager.
7. Check your public IP using any site like Seemyip.com
8. Give this IP to your friend along with sql server instance name
9. On remote machine - enter IP\ServerName with credentials for sa.

Answer (score 2):

OP you just need a dynamic DNS Record (for free at dyndns.org) and then you can create a port forwarding on your Router/Firewall to your SQL server.
That way your SQL Server will be accessible over the internet. Just update your connection string with the dynamic DNS entry that you registered.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) link would be helpful to set the configuration.The link tells how to manipulate connection string according to scenarios.

Here is your:

```
  Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```